# What is the probability density function of the cosine of a gaussian random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I want to find the probability density function of $Y=\cos(X)$, where $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. The answer is known when $X$ is uniformly distributed $U(-\pi, \pi)$ and it is an arcsin pdf, given by,
$f_X(x) = {1\over{\pi\sqrt{(1-x^2)}}}$.
But when $X$ is Gaussian, there are infinite roots of $Y=\cos(X)$ and the solution looks messy. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by an "arccosine pdf"?

Comment: It isn't going to have a nice form. Was the problem you were given to find the expected value of cos(X)? If so, thats a significantly easier problem -- look at the real part of the characteristic function evaluated at $1$.

Comment: Avraham: I have edited the question above with the details on the arcsin (not arccos - sorry) distribution.

Comment: Batman: I have found one "messy" solution here, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35260/resultant-probability-distribution-when-taking-the-cosine-of-gaussian-distribute                                    But I was told this becomes Wrapped Normal PDF which can be approximated by a uniform, which I don't see how.

Comment: Well, see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution  , but this is not your distribution.  You distribution has a normal wrapped onto a circle, then marginalized onto the $x$-axis, but having to transform from $\mathrm{d}x$s to $\mathrm{d}s$s, line elements along the circle.  (Details are worked out in arc length from calculus.)

Comment: Eric Towers: Is it possible to share the material you are referring to or a citation that I could look into? Thanks.