# Function of normal random variables is normal

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

I am trying to understand a paper related to brownian [motions](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00622142), and right in the begginining it is claimed that $$X_t=\sqrt{t}\bigg( G_1 \cos ( W_{a + \ln t}) + G_2 \sin( W_{a + \ln t})\bigg)$$ has the same distribution as a standard Brownian motion, for $t \geq \exp(-a), a \geq 0$, $G_i$'s standard normaly distributed and where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. It is assumed that the $G_i$'s and $W_t$ are all mutually independent.

To see that the expected value is $0$ is straightforward, but of course this does not suffice. My attempt then was to try to compute the distribution of $X_t$ using conditional probabilities and taking advantage of the independence, but I have read however that the sine and cosine of normal distributions are not easily [derived](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838005/what-is-the-probability-density-function-of-the-cosine-of-a-gaussian-random-vari). So probably this was not the author's approach.

Is there maybe some "general fact" I can use to prove this claim?

Thanks!

Comment: For the variance equal to $t$, we get it this way.
$$E[X_t^2]/t=E[ G_1^2 \cos^2 ( W_{a + \ln t}) + G_2^2 \sin^2( W_{a + \ln t})+2G_1.G_2.\cos^2 ( W_{a + \ln t}).\sin^2( W_{a + \ln t})]=E[G_1^2].E[\cos^2 ( W_{a + \ln t})]+E[G_2^2].E[\sin^2 ( W_{a + \ln t})]+2.E[G_1].E[G_2].E[\cos^2 ( W_{a + \ln t}).\sin^2( W_{a + \ln t})]$$
$$=1.E[\cos^2 ( W_{a + \ln t})]+1.E[\sin^2 ( W_{a + \ln t})]+0.0..E[\cos^2 ( W_{a + \ln t}).\sin^2( W_{a + \ln t})]=E[\cos^2 ( W_{a + \ln t})+\sin^2 ( W_{a + \ln t})]=1$$. So we've got that $X_t$ has 0 mean and variance equal to t, which is necessary but not sufficient

Comment: Maybe using Lévy characterisation of Brownian motion would get you there if you can prove that its quadratic variation is equal to $t$, we have that its second moment is equal to $t$ which is not too far

Comment: @TheBridge Thank you for your comment. What do you think of my solution?

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to compute the characteristic function of $Y_t:=X_t/\sqrt{t}$ and check that it is equal to $e^{-t^2/2}$. This is since $X_t \sim B_t \iff X_t/\sqrt{t} \sim B_1$ which is of course a standard normal variable.

Write $Y_t$ as the sum $X_1 + X_2$ and note that conditional on $W_t$, $X_1 \sim N(0, \cos^2(W_t)$) and $X_2 \sim N(0, \sin^2(W_t)$) and that both are independent. Using iterated expectations and the fact that the expected value of a product of independent random variables is the product of the corresponding expectations we have:

$$
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[e^{it Y_t}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{it Y_t}|W_t]] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{it X_1}e^{it X_2}|W_t]] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{it X_1}|W_t]\mathbb{E}[e^{it X_2}|W_t]] \\
= \mathbb{E}[e^{-t^2\cos^2(W_t)/2} e^{-t^2\sin^2(W_t)/2}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{-t^2/2}] = e^{-t^2/2}
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: Well for the characteristic function you should use two different indices one for time and one the parameter of the charactisitic function and not a single $t$ which is a little ambiguous otherwise. The solution is ok except for the sign in the exponent which should be negative i.e. $ e^{-t^2/2}$ : look at the example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)